# Prevent images saved on sd card to appear in gallery

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-gallery

I have seen that appending a '.' before the file name prevents it from showing up.
But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: creat blank .nomedia file on the same folder where you store your images

Comment: @qwr - will try it n let u know :)

Comment: In which type you are saving your images?

Comment: does the image type even matter?

Comment: @qwr - Yes you're solution works.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use many ways to achieve it:-

1. Change the extension of your image file to any unknown image format ex:- .txt, .abc etc.
2. Convert Image to Base64 format and save it to as a text File. when you wants to use it you can read it from that file.
   with this approach you can also use encryption or decryption technique to implement Security.

Comment: Haven't tried this as qwr's solution worked for me... thanks for the suggestion though. :)